# php int comparison "smaller or equal than" returns empty or null?

Tags: php, boolean, comparison

The following expression

```
echo ('dfsdfds: '.(int)$item[0] . '   ' . 
(int)$box[0] . '   ' . 
( ( (int)$item[0] <= (int)$box[0] )?true:false) );
```

echoes this

```
dfsdfds: 70 25
```

The values come form a StdClass Object so the values are stored as a string, therefore the cast to int.
I would expect the comparison expression <= to return either 1 or 0 but not null or empty... 
What is wrong? what am I not thinking thorugh? 
I have tried to replace true with TRUE and false with FALSE,
I have tried to output the expression itself
 but the output didn't change... it's always empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to some [strange (although documented) default behaviour](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) in PHP when converting between data types:

> Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).

You can change your code to e.g. this to see a difference:

```
echo ('dfsdfds: '.(int)$item[0] . '   ' . 
(int)$box[0] . '   ' . 
( ( (int)$item[0] <= (int)$box[0] )?'true':'false') );
```

Or if you want to have `0` or `1` respectively, you can force a cast to `int`:

```
echo ('dfsdfds: '.(int)$item[0] . '   ' . 
(int)$box[0] . '   ' . 
( ( (int)$item[0] <= (int)$box[0] )?true:(int)false) );
```

(`true` is already automatically converted to `"1"`)

Comment: Thanks mate! I thought this was bizarre behaviour.